# How do I reuse a component and make it generic in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a component for each svg icons. For that i'm providing the following properties for it,

```
export interface IconProperties{
  width?: string | number;
  height?: string | number;
  size?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
  onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<SVGElement>;
  disabled?: boolean;
}
```

Now to create Component for each icon, I'm doing

```
import * as React from "react";
import Attachment from "../../svg/attach.svg";
const AttachmentIcon = (props: IconProperties) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Attachment
        width={props.width}
        height={props.height}
        onClick={props.onClick}
        style={
         {props.size}
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AttachmentIcon;
```

User will call icon component in the following way :

```
import * as React from "react";
import AttachmentIcon from "./iconComponents/AttachmentIcon";

const onClickOperation = (): void => { 
  alert("Icon Clicked!");
};

const DemoApp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AttachmentIcon
        width="60px"
        height="60px"
        onClick={onClickOperation}
        disabled={true}
        size={"small"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DemoApp;
```

Here my properties is same for all the icons and I have to keep on repeating the same lines of code for each icon to make it as a component. How do I avoid duplicating same code for every icon.

Comment: Looks like `Attachment` is already a component. Why do you need that wrapper?

Comment: @Aleksey L Like Attachment, I have 50+ icons to be converted into Components

Comment: Of course it is possible to create a factory which will do all the boilerplate. The question is why can't you use `Attachment` directly, what's the point of this wrapper?

Comment: I can use `Attachment` directly, but I have to add custom properties to it (like size, onClick etc). That's the reason I'm trying out to create a wrapper on top of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a factory method to generate Component.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Attachment from "../../svg/attach.svg";
import Email from "../../svg/email.svg";

const createSvgIcon = Component: React.Component<any> => (props: IconProperties) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component
        width={props.width}
        height={props.height}
        onClick={props.onClick}
        style={
         {props.size}
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export const EmailIcon = createSvgIcon(Email)

const AttachmentIcon = createSvgIcon(Attachment)
export default AttachmentIcon;
```

Answer (score 0):

in `AttachmentIcon.module.css`

```
 .iconStyle{
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            disabled:true;
            size:small;
    }
```

in Js file

```
import classes from './AttachmentIcon.module.css';
<AttachmentIcon className={classes.iconStyle} onClick={onClickOperation} />
```